# How to get html content remotely and open locally

Tags: titanium

I want to get the content remotely for a html page and open locally in the webview. But I want this html to have access to the `Ti` namespace, so it implies that the html must be running locally.
Have tried to create the webview passing the content as the "html" parameter, but `Ti` namespace doesnt work that way.

Then, I tried to write the content to a html file on `Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory`. The page opens OK, but the `Ti` namespace doesnt work on the html either.

Finaly, I created a html file in assets folder on the project and when I get the html code I try to write on it so I could open using `'url' : '/myfile.html'`. But when I try to write it gives `java.io.IOException: read only`

How can I achieve this? Again: I'm trying to get a html content remotely and run locally so I can have access to `Ti` namespace.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean that you want the Ti namespace to work?  What are you trying to do exactly?  As far as I've known, you can create events tied to functions on the html page and then send them to your Ti App for processing.

Comment: Yes, thats it. I want to use Ti.App.fireEvent from the html. But for this to work, that means, for the "Ti" to be available on the html's javascript, the html file must be running locally. I want to achieve this from a remote html.

Answer (score 0):

I messed up during my testings. Downloading the html and then opening the webview passing the html code to "html" parameter on the webview works just fine. The  fireEvent works that way inside the html.

It was not working because it was other problem not related that I fixed.